# How to use spatial audio correctly in RealityKit in combination with AirPods?

Tags: swift, audio, bluetooth, realitykit

I am using RealityKit for my app and tried to use spatial audio like this:

```swift
let resource = try AudioFileResource.load(named: "CardMatchingSound.mp3",
                                      inputMode: .spatial,
                                loadingStrategy: .preload,
                                     shouldLoop: false)
entity.playAudio(resource)
```

I also already tried with `prepareAudio` and `play` afterwards and when using the app without any headphones it even works correctly, I can hear the spatial audio correctly on the device.

The only problem I have, is as soon as I use AirPods, the first time playing the sound, a huge lag appears and sometimes it either doesn't play any audio anymore at all or it still works after the lag with constantly putting `[BTAudio] XPC server error: Connection invalid` into the console/logs.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? Do I have to ask for Bluetooth permission first? That would be kinda weird as I just want to play audio, no matter what device is connected. Note: I am also running an `AVAudioPlayer` for the background music in my game.

Comment: I just tried Apple's example code (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/creating_a_game_with_scene_understanding) and there it happens as well - is it maybe an internal problem or something with my AirPods?

Answer (score 1):

#### Spatial audio in RealityKit

My answer depends on the fact: what kind of spatial audio you really mean. In order to play [RealityKit Spatial Audio](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/audiofileresource) in AR/VR environment, you need to use files of `.aiff`, `.mp3` or `.caf` formats. For best results, use `MONO` files. However, if you mean `Dolby`, then RealityKit doesn't explicitly support it (there's an `ambient` InputMode that is spatialized, but ignoring listener position, and accounting only for user orientation).

My `Shure Aonic 50` wireless headphones reproduce RealityKit's spatial sound perfectly. There are no obvious premises for Apple AirPods not being able to play such an audio in AR scene.

Here is how your code should look like:

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

extension ViewController {       
    fileprivate func loadAudio() {       
        do {
            let audioResource = try AudioFileResource.load(
                                               named: "audio.mp3",
                                                  in: nil,
                                           inputMode: .spatial,
                                     loadingStrategy: .preload,
                                          shouldLoop: false)

            self.audioController = aEntity.prepareAudio(audioResource)
            self.audioController?.speed = 1.2
            self.audioController?.gain = 30                
            self.audioController?.play()                
        } catch {
            print("Get error while loading audio...")
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    let aEntity = Entity()
    let aAnchor = AnchorEntity()
    var audioController: AudioPlaybackController? = nil
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                    
        self.aAnchor.addChild(aEntity)
        self.arView.scene.anchors.append(aAnchor)
        self.loadAudio()
        
        // 100 meters away
        aEntity.move(to: Transform(translation: [0,0,-100]),
             relativeTo: nil, 
               duration: 10)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I am not sure if it's MONO or Dolby to be honest, but the thing is, it actually plays the sounds and the spatial sound works perfectly as well, but I still get those XPC server error logs constantly as soon as I connect my AirPods. I even tried it with your example code and with Apple's example code and this still happens - so I guess it's an Apple internal issue? Could you check if you get the same error logs for your example?

Comment: If spatial audio plays perfectly, but you are confused by errors in the console - turn off error messages. To turn debug messages off, use the following commands – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69494111/why-so-many-debug-error-using-arkit-and-realitykit/72076047#72076047

Comment: Haha I would rather prefer to fix the error - but as your name shows up most when it's about RealityKit/ARKit, I guess you would know if it would be an issue/critical bug - so thanks for the help!

Comment: You're right, not all RealityKit's errors are debuggable, and especially those that are not directly related to RealityKit (I mean AirPods). Most of errors here are internal C++ errors.